# Save a video with different file name each time we give a Trigger in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, filenames, store

This is the process I am trying to achieve :

1. Live Stream is captured from webcam and the Image frames are stored in a particular folder.
2. Now, If I give a trigger the frames in that folder at that moment should be converted into a video and get saved with name eg. video1.mp4.
3. Now again if I press a trigger another video should be saved as video2.mp4.

I have attached the code here . If I press R , it is saving one video as a0.mp4 . But If I press again, nothing seems to happen.

def frametovideo(img_array):

```
for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
img_array = []
videono = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

for filename in glob.glob('./output/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)

path = 'a' + str(videono) + '.mp4'
out = cv2.VideoWriter(path,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 15, size)

while True:
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if ret == True:
        
        cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xff
        if k == ord('r'):
            frametovideo(img_array)
            videono += 1
```

Comment: What is the **exact** problem in _"the process I am trying to achieve"_? Not obvious where you are stuck... Are you asking how to capture a webcam? What is a trigger, did you actually mean **when I run a function**? If just asking about filename changing, then simply use an **int** variable that increments and is also appended to filename variable. Example logic:  `myInt++; filename = "video" + myInt + ".mp4";`

Comment: @VC.One Thank you so much for pointing out that I had to be very specific . I am new to this platform and learning my ways around here . I have added the code and let me know if you can be of any help.

Comment: Try cutting out that `out = cv2.VideoWriter...` line and pasting it after bottom `videono += 1`. Now every time you press `R` does it save a different file? PS: I don't use Python so its strange to me that you can use keypresses in the middle of a While loop.

Answer (score 0):

You do not understanding how to save filenames Do not used operator. Used string format python 3.8 or later. Try this in below. Actually, you can modified key press.

```
import cv2
import os


i = 1

wait = 0


video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while video.isOpened():
    ret, img = video.read()

    cv2.imshow('live video', img)

    # wait for user to press any key
    key = cv2.waitKey(100)

    # wait variable is to calculate waiting time
    wait = wait+100

    if key == ord('q'):
        break
    # when it reaches to 5000 milliseconds
    # we will save that frame in given folder
    if wait == 5000:
        filename = f'Frame_{str(i)}.jpg'
        
        # Save the images in given path
        cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
        i += 1
        wait = 0

# close the camera
video.release()

# close open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Btw,look in line #27-34. Correct way to do this `if __name__ == "__main__":`